# Should we vote down on answers that misunderstand the question?

Tags: discussion

Should we vote down on answers that misunderstand the question?

[What does 'require' mean in this statement of Danto's view on (institutional) art?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/65369/what-does-require-mean-in-this-statement-of-dantos-view-on-institutional-ar)

is why I ask.

Though it's been since cleaned up totally to my satisfaction.

---

This isn't a great example of misunderstanding, but it's a general question.